# How to have jQuery filtered file types on selecting files before uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery-File-Upload and I would like to do filter file types on selecting. That means every files with non-accepted extension would be hidden on file explorer widget and user cannot see them.
I tried to import value for "acceptFileTypes" but it only validates the file type after selecting, and this is not what I want.
Anyone help please?

This is just my sample code. I cannot show the official. Sorry for this one.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//localhost/',
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            process: [
                {
                    action: 'load',
                    fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                    maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
                },
                {
                    action: 'resize',
                    maxWidth: 1440,
                    maxHeight: 900
                },
                {
                    action: 'save'
                }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: your code please

Comment: @Rajaji :D kay karnay o . i am with you on this.

Comment: I've just updated with some sample code. Sorry that I cannot show the official one. Hope it can help.

Comment: @omglolgg I have answered to your question, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) attribute to filter the file types. Refer my sample code below.

```html
<!--Code to access only for excel files-->
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```